# ggplot2 + gridExtra: how to ensure geom_bar in different size plot grobs result in exact same bar width

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is motivated by further exploring this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301738/ggplot2-how-to-drop-unused-factors-in-the-axis-in-a-faceted-bar-plot-but-not-ha). The problem with the accepted solution becomes more obvious when there is a greater disparity in the number of bars per facet. Take a look at this data and the resultant plot using that solution:

```
# create slightly contrived data to better highlight width problems
data <- data.frame(ID=factor(c(rep(1,9), rep(2,6), rep(3,6), rep(4,3), rep(5,3))),
                   TYPE=factor(rep(1:3,length(ID)/3)),
                   TIME=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)),
                   VAL=runif(27))

# implement previously suggested solution
base.width <- 0.9
data$w <- base.width
# facet two has 3 bars compared to facet one's 5 bars
data$w[data$TIME==2] <- base.width * 3/5
# facet 3 has 1 bar compared to facet one's 5 bars
data$w[data$TIME==3] <- base.width * 1/5
ggplot(data, aes(x=ID, y=VAL, fill=TYPE)) +
  facet_wrap(~TIME, ncol=1, scale="free") +
  geom_bar(position="stack", aes(width = w),stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: widths all the same but spacing is bad]

You'll notice the widths look exactly right, but the whitespace in facet 3 is quite glaring. There is no easy way to fix this in ggplot2 that I have seen yet (facet_wrap does not have a `space` option).

Next step is to try to solve this using gridExtra:

```
# create each of the three plots, don't worry about legend for now
p1 <- ggplot(data[data$TIME==1,], aes(x=ID, y=VAL, fill=TYPE)) +
  facet_wrap(~ TIME, ncol=1) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", show_guide=FALSE) +
  coord_flip()
p2 <- ggplot(data[data$TIME==2,], aes(x=ID, y=VAL, fill=TYPE)) +
  facet_wrap(~ TIME, ncol=1) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", show_guide=FALSE) +
  coord_flip()
p3 <- ggplot(data[data$TIME==3,], aes(x=ID, y=VAL, fill=TYPE)) +
  facet_wrap(~ TIME, ncol=1) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", show_guide=FALSE) +
  coord_flip()

# use similar arithmetic to try and get layout correct
require(gridExtra)
heights <- c(5, 3, 1) / sum(5, 3, 1)
print(arrangeGrob(p1 ,p2, p3, ncol=1,
            heights=heights))
```

[image: widths wrong]

You'll notice I used the same arithmetic previously suggested based off the number of bars per facet, but in this case it ends up horribly wrong. This seems to be because there are extra "constant height" elements that I need to take into consideration in the math.

Another complication (I believe) is that the final output (and whether or not the widths match) will also depend on the width and height of where I'm outputting the final grob to, whether its in a R/RStudio environment, or to a PNG file.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: with `ggplot_build` you could modify directly the height of each panel in your first solution. kohske has posted examples here

Comment: @baptiste thanks, will take a look and update question soon

Answer (score 5):

Something like this appear to work, but it doesn't - not completely. It has the appearance of working because the levels of the ID factor are sequential. Anything else, and `scale = "free"` fails. But it might be possible to develop further. The method uses `facet_grid`, and thus `space = "free"` can be used. The method uses geom_rect to layer differently coloured rectangles on top of each other. It needs cumulative sums to be calculated so that the right-hand edge of each rectangle can be positioned.

```
data <- data.frame(ID=factor(c(rep(1,9), rep(2,6), rep(3,6), rep(4,3), rep(5,3))),
                   TYPE=factor(rep(1:3,3)),
                   TIME=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)),
                   VAL=runif(27))

library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

# Get the cumulative sums
data = ddply(data, .(ID, TIME), mutate, CUMSUMVAL = cumsum(VAL))

ggplot(data, aes(x=VAL, y = as.numeric(ID), fill=TYPE)) +
   geom_rect(data = subset(data, TYPE == 3), aes(xmin = 0, xmax = CUMSUMVAL, ymin = as.numeric(ID)-.2, ymax = as.numeric(ID)+.2)) +
   geom_rect(data = subset(data, TYPE == 2), aes(xmin = 0, xmax = CUMSUMVAL, ymin = as.numeric(ID)-.2, ymax = as.numeric(ID)+.2)) +
   geom_rect(data = subset(data, TYPE == 1), aes(xmin = 0, xmax = CUMSUMVAL, ymin = as.numeric(ID)-.2, ymax = as.numeric(ID)+.2)) +
   facet_grid(TIME~., space = "free", scale="free") +
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:5), expand = c(0, 0.2))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  OR really thick lines work a little better (I think)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=VAL, y = ID, colour=TYPE)) +
       geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 3), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
       geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 2), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
       geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 1), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
       facet_grid(TIME~., space = "free", scale="free")
```

[image]

**Additional Edit**  Taking the data from your earleir post, and modifying it a little.
**Updated** `opts` is deprecated; using `theme` instead.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), class = "factor"), TYPE = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8"), class = "factor"), TIME = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("One", "Five", "Fifteen"), class = "factor"), VAL = c(0.937377670081332, 
0.522220720537007, 0.278690102742985, 0.967633064137772, 0.116124767344445, 
0.0544306698720902, 0.470229141646996, 0.62017166428268, 0.195459847105667, 
0.732876230962574, 0.996336271753535, 0.983087373664603, 0.666449476964772, 
0.291554537601769, 0.167933790013194, 0.860138458199799, 0.172361251665279, 
0.833266809117049, 0.620465772924945, 0.786503327777609, 0.761877260869369, 
0.425386636285111, 0.612077651312575, 0.178726130630821, 0.528709076810628, 
0.492527724476531, 0.472576208412647, 0.0702785139437765, 0.696220921119675, 
0.230852259788662, 0.359884874196723, 0.518227979075164, 0.259466265095398, 
0.149970305617899, 0.00682218233123422, 0.463400925742462, 0.924704828299582, 
0.229068386601284)), .Names = c("ID", "TYPE", "TIME", "VAL"), row.names = c(NA, 
-38L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

data = ddply(df, .(ID, TIME), mutate, CUMSUMVAL = cumsum(VAL))

ggplot(data, aes(x=VAL, y = ID, colour=TYPE)) +
           geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 6), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
           geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 5), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
           geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 4), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
           geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 3), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
           geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 2), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
           geom_segment(data = subset(data, TYPE == 1), aes(x = 0, xend = CUMSUMVAL, y = ID, yend = ID), size = 10) +
           facet_grid(TIME~., space = "free", scale="free") +
           theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Clever! This would work except the facet labels are on the right side as well as in my actual data my ID column is actually a factor and sometimes a particular ID, TIME combo will have be missing a type. Testing this now to see how well it works with my actual data.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the gtable doesn't help, unfortunately, as the bar width is in relative units,

```
g = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
panels = which(sapply(g$heights, attr, "unit") == "null")
g$heights[[panels[1]]] <- unit(5, "null")
g$heights[[panels[2]]] <- unit(3, "null")
g$heights[[panels[3]]] <- unit(1, "null")
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: So back to arranging the individual facets via gridExtra then?