# R: horizontal bar charts with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to create a multiple grouped bar chart but I haven't figured out how to get the right layout. 
I have created one which shows at least the right thing but the bars are vertical instead of horizontal.

Code:

```
sex <- c('F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F','M','M','M','M')
type <-c('XL1','XL1','XL1','XL2','XL2','XL2','XL2','XL2','XL2')
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
smoke <- c('yes','yes','no','yes','no','yes','no','no','yes')
improved <- c(12,9.8,13,4,7,9,6.5,12.2,-1) 
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(sex,type,ID,smoke,improved)) 

base <- ggplot(dat, aes(fill = interaction(sex,type,smoke))) +
        geom_bar(position = 'dodge',stat='identity') 
base + aes(x = factor(ID), y=improved) + 
       facet_grid(.~type+sex, scales = "free_x", space = "free")
```

The problem is that I have another grouping variable except type and sex and all three have in the real dataset long labels. I could rotate them by 90 degrees but I prefer to rotate the whole graph by 90 degrees and flip_coord() doesn't work... 
The solution mentioned at the end of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301738/ggplot2-drop-unused-factors-in-a-faceted-bar-plot-but-not-have-differing-bar-wi!) isn't really nice. Also because the grouping variables are on the right and not on the left.

I'm grateful for any advice.
Thanks,

Anja

Comment: I believe it's `coord_flip()` and using that gives the expected horizontal bar facets

Answer (score 0):

I am confused why `coord_flip()` won't work?

```
base <- ggplot(dat, aes(fill = interaction(sex,type,smoke))) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge',stat='identity') 
base <- base + aes(x = factor(ID), y=improved) +  facet_grid(.~type+sex, scales = "free_x", space = "free")
base <- base + coord_flip()
```

You can adjust the legend position by using the following:

```
base <- base + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Which gives:
[image: rotated]

Or maybe something like this would be more appropriate, two columns for the legend:

```
base <- base + theme(legend.position = "bottom") + guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

Which gives:
[image: rotated_col_legend]

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention that coord_flip() works but I can't figure out how to plot the pictures below each other. So I would need a option as par(mfrow=c(3,1)). Because I would have at least 15 charts side by side and I want to compare the height of the charts easily. And the width of the charts should be the same then.

Comment: Can you not use `facet_wrap` then?
    `facet_wrap(~type+sex, ncol = 1, nrow = 3)`

Comment: Then I got the error message: "Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting"

Comment: Hmm, this worked for me:
`base <- ggplot(dat, aes(fill = interaction(sex,type,smoke))) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge',stat='identity')`
`base <- base + aes(x = factor(ID), y=improved) +  facet_wrap(~type+sex, ncol = 1, nrow = 3)`
`base <- base + coord_flip()`
`base`

Comment: Yes, but the option with free scale for ID not, or? So there are all 9 persons listed and just a few have bars. That is also not really nice. Could it really be, that there is no option? Or is there maybe a way with the data set in "long" format?

Comment: I don't think you can use free scales with `coord_flip()`. I just get an error message.
`Error in facet_render.wrap(plot$facet, panel, plot$coordinates, plot_theme(plot),  : 
  ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip.`
Sorry I can't be a better help. I only started learning ggplot last week.